# Yii relation STAT with multiple columns

Tags: php, yii

i'm trying to get a STAT relation from a Review table. This is my code

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'avarageRating' => array(SELF::STAT, 'Reviews', array('make_code'=>'make_code', 'model_code'=>'model_code', 'year'=>'year'), 'select' => 'AVG(overall_rating)'),
    }
```

the table would look something like this

```
make_code | model_code | year | overall_rating
01        | 02         | 2015 | 4.2
01        | 03         | 2014 | 4.0
01        | 02         | 2015 | 3.0
```

i want to get the `overall_rating` average for all rows that have the same `make_code`, `model_code` and `year`

example, make_code 01, model_code 02 and year 2015. `(4.2+3.0 / 2)`, `$model->avarageRating` should give me **3.6**

Right now, when i call the relation using `$model->avarageRating;` i get an error

`preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

**EDITED:**

```
function getavarageRating() {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->select='ROUND(AVG(overall_rating), 1) AS avg, COUNT(overall_rating) AS total';
        $criteria->addCondition("make_code=:make_code");
        $criteria->addCondition("model_code=:model_code");
        $criteria->addCondition("year=:year");
        $criteria->params = array(':make_code' => $this->make_code, ':model_code' => $this->model_code, ':year' => $this->year);


        $query = Reviews::model()->find($criteria);

        return $query;
    }
```

i added this function in my model, and this workws. but i there a way to use relations instead?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you get a collection for your result  so you should access by index , try accessing  the first element as

```
 $model[0]->avarageRating;
```